# Accessing Old Cell Value in BindingDataChanged Event and Cell Location in Excel using office.js (Office Add-ins)

Tags: javascript, excel, office365, office-addins, office-app

I have a table in Excel and I want to detect changes when the user modifies the cell values. In order to reflect those particular changes, I need to know the cell location and old cell value. I was able to achieve this in an Excel VBA/COM add-in, but not with JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any straightforward way to get the location and old cell value at this point. But here are some workarounds that you might use until there's a better way:

-Keep track of the contents of the user's table: you can get the entire table when it first gets linked to the add-in. Add a binding and listen for [BindingDataChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142247.aspx) events to detect updates. Every time there's an update, you can manually compare it with your own copy. When the add-in is restarted you can reinitialize your in-memory copy using the [Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/fp142179.aspx) object.

-Keep track of the user's selections within the table using the [BindingSelectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161088.aspx) event and the [Document.SelectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161062.aspx) event. Then whenever the data in the table changes, determine using the saved [BindingSelectionChangedEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142148.aspx) which cell was selected when the user made a change. Note that changes to the table can happen even if the user does nothing - for example, another add-in could change content. Also note that the BindingSelectionChangedEventArgs report the final position of the user's selection after it changes, not the initial position, so you'll need to use the second-last position whenever the user changes a cell but keeps her selection inside the table.

Also, you might not actually need to use the workarounds above, depending on what your add-in is doing: for example, if the table is small you could overwrite the necessary columns entirely whenever there's a change.

-Michael (Program Manager on the add-ins team)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but comparing the copy of huge tables with new one would be expensive task and is there any event for tracking second last selection (  I guess no ) ?

Comment: That's right. You could track the second-last selection manually by watching both selection-related events and keeping the coordinates in memory.

Comment: So, in this case using Excel-Addins will be better instead of Office Apps ( JavaScript API ) ?

Comment: If you need the add-in to work on other platforms like Excel for iPad and Excel Online then the JavaScript APIs should work with the workarounds I've suggested. If not then COM/VSTO should work and might be faster to implement if you're already familiar with that technology.

Comment: Yes I have made this functionality in COM/VSTO